# Subjects that, while still being on-topic here, you can get better response on our sister sites:

Tags: discussion, mathoverflow, help-center, stackexchange

The [On-Topic page](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) says:

> There are certain subjects that, while still being on-topic here, you can get better response on our sister sites: [...]

I suggest adding to this list:

- teaching mathematics and the process of learning mathematics: [Mathematics Educators](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/)
- signal, image and video processing: [Signal Processing](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/)

Also, two corrections for the line

> Research-level mathematics — Math Overflow

"[MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/tour)" should be written as one word (unlike Stack Overflow). And the name should be a hyperlink.

Comment: I also think that the sentence quoted in the title does not flow very well, but I don't have a better alternative.

Comment: I'm not sure about MathEds, since it's still in beta.

Comment: @AsafKaragila So are Computer Science, Computational Science, and DSP. These are not paths for migration, these are signposts for users. A question posted by a user who followed a sign is an "organic" question, not a migrated one -- and betas need those.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Then again, they would probably like the increased traffic.

Comment: @Thomas: Sure they would; **words:** Yeah, you have a point there.

Comment: It's actually Math Overthrow...............I believe that originates with me. Used in all correspondence related to MO, any filenames or directories on my computer, and so on.

Comment: @WillJagy [StackOverthrow](http://stackoverthrow.herokuapp.com/) also exists. It's somewhat less useful than the original SO.

Comment: @wordsthatendinGRY, i really thought I was original. Related: I find many books for the math phobic, varied titles. However, even after the Ben Affleck movie, no book titled The Fear of All Sums. I think this is an opportunity.

Comment: @wordsthatendinGRY I agree about the first sentence: I don't even think it's correct English at the moment. "There are certain subjects that, while still on-topic for MSE, might be better addressed by one of our sister sites."  Or, "There are certain questions that, while still on-topic for MSE, might receive better responses on one of our sister sites."

Comment: @SpamIAm: I cp'd your first suggestion.

Comment: You should delete that comment before someone steals your idea! (Heck, I might steal it!)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Done. See https://math.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

I also moved the caveat about *Mathematica* up a bit: the site is now graduated and people really are much, much better off asking Mathematica questions there than here.

Comment: speaking of which, does it make sense to add a pointer to puzzling.SE (which is now in beta too) for recreational mathematic questions? It is impossible to draw a sharp line for which question goes where, but knowing about the other site could be nice.

Comment: To be honest, I didn't even know puzzling.SE existed. I would prefer to wait at least until they have [defined what they consider to be on-topic](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) before I advertise them to users.

Comment: Thanks, but now it seems that the repetition of "Stack Exchange" at the end of site names is ...  repetitive. `other Stack Exchange sites such as: Physics - Stack Exchange, Electrical Engineering - Stack Exchange, Quantitative Finance - Stack Exchange`... When the list is  preceded by "one of our sister sites" or "other Stack Exchange sites", it should be clear what the sites are. By the way, you don't have -SE after TeX site's name. And is it name really "TeX, LaTeX and Friends"? I would not know from looking at the site.

Comment: @wordsthatendinGRY: the blah -- stackexchange names came from when sites were in beta without a defined name. Perhaps I should edit them. The name for TeX was taken from [its area 51 proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/2148/tex-latex-and-friends) and I perhaps should double check with the mods there to see what their proper name is.

Comment: It appears to be [TeX-LaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: @wordsthatendinGRY: yes, I just heard back from Joseph too in the mod chat room. Edited again. Anything else I can change while you are looking at it?

Comment: Looks good now.

Comment: @WillieWong Small typo - the physics bullet should read "it is fine to ask *about* the mathematical model...", or something similar.

Comment: @MattPressland: fixed.